# Как отсортировать вложенный массив объектов по ключу и значению?

Tags: javascript

Как отсортировать вложенный массив объектов по ключу и значению?

```js
let obj = {
  'ab': {
    0: {'status': 'se'},
    1: {'status': 'ae'},
    2: {'status': 'be'}
   },
  'fb': {
    0: {'status': 'me'},
    1: {'status': 'aa'},
    2: {'status': 'bc'}
   },
  'ca': {
    0: {'status': 'qe'},
    1: {'status': 'wa'},
    2: {'status': 'ba'}
   }
};

console.log(obj);
```

В итоге должно быть так:

```
let obj = {
  'ab': {
     0: {'status': 'ae'},
     1: {'status': 'be'},
     2: {'status': 'se'}
   },
   'ca': {
     0: {'status': 'ba'}
     1: {'status': 'qe'},
     2: {'status': 'wa'},
   },
   'fb': {
     0: {'status': 'aa'},
     1: {'status': 'bc'},
     2: {'status': 'me'}
   }
};
```

`sort` не выйдет использовать, так как это не массив `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  'ab': {
    0: {'status': 'se'},
    1: {'status': 'ae'},
    2: {'status': 'be'}
   },
  'fb': {
    0: {'status': 'me'},
    1: {'status': 'aa'},
    2: {'status': 'bc'}
   },
  'ca': {
    0: {'status': 'qe'},
    1: {'status': 'wa'},
    2: {'status': 'ba'}
   }
};

const o1 = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((r, i) => (r[i] = obj[i], r), {});
console.log(o1);
```

Аналогично - с `values` каждого подобъекта.

Comment: а как по `values` сделать? По ключу понял как, а вот по значению ключа что то застрял